# 'Error compiling builtin' while executing JavaScript code in JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, ios, javascriptcore

I execute the following javascript code in iOS using JavaScriptCore framework. The javascript code is browserified.

```
var myCallback = undefined;

*browserify logic*
{
 1: [function(require, module, exports) {

     var q = require('./user');

     var p = new Promise(function(resolved, reject) {
                            myCallback = function() {
                                resolved('test');
                            }
                         });

     p.then(function(x) {printFunc('test');}).catch(function(e){printFunc('test2');});

     q();

     }, {
     "./user": 2
     }],
 2: [function(require, module, exports) {
     function q() {
        printFunc("Callback called!");
        myCallback();
        printFunc("Callback called end!");
     }
     module.exports = q;
     }, {}]
 }, {}, [1]);
```

*printFunc* is a method implemented in Swift that just prints something to console. Here is the implementation:

```
    let printFunction : @convention(block) (String) -> String = {input in
        print("|\(input)|")
        return ""
    }
```

The problem is that I am receiving the following error:

```
|Callback called!|
Error compiling builtin: Invalid private name '@capabilities'
|Callback called end!|
```

Even more strange is that if I remove the prints "Callback called!" and "Callback called end!" the code executes without error and it prints "test".

Did you guys encountered this strange behaviour? Is it a known bug with Promise implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the JavascriptCore's Promise implementation. I opened a ticket at Apple and it is confirmed.

An workaround is to come with your own Promise implementation.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Do you have a working implementation of Promise? Or the text of Apple's response so I can understand how to workaround the root problem?

Comment: If anyone is curious, I used Bluebird's implementation of Promise and it worked as a drop in. All problems immediately disappeared.